# How do I solve the animation problem in XAML C #?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I want to animate a reflection on a button. Can you tell me why it doesn't work? My guess is that the whole point is that my element is nested and therefore it cannot refer to it in order to animate.

```
<Grid Background="Black">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard
                x:Name="animation"
                Storyboard.TargetName="btn"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                <DoubleAnimation
                    RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                    From="-100"
                    To="100"
                    Duration="0:0:1" />
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Button x:Name="btn"
            Width="200"
            Height="50"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="LightGreen">
                        <TextBlock
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Text="TRY FOR FREE" />
                        <Grid
                            x:Name="grid"
                            Width="20"
                            Height="70">
                            <Grid.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,2" EndPoint="0,0">
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1.1" Color="Yellow" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="Transparent" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Grid.Background>
                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="30" CenterX="20" />
                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="transform" X="0" />
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7Fs4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.  One is what you've already stated, which is you've defined the `Storyboard` at a location where it doesn't have access to the `Storyboard.TargetProperty`.  Your second problem is that you don't show any XAML or any code that triggers the animation to start.  Here's an example showing the correction location for the `Storyboard`, and also an `EventTrigger` to get the `Storyboard` to start when the `Grid` is loaded.

**EDIT: This is a WPF solution. For UWP, keep scrolling.**

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Button x:Name="btn" Width="200" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid Background="LightGreen">
                    <TextBlock
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Text="TRY FOR FREE" />
                    <Grid
                        x:Name="grid"
                        Width="20"
                        Height="70">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="animateme" x:Name="animation"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                                <DoubleAnimation RepeatBehavior="Forever" From="-100" To="100" Duration="0:0:1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,2" EndPoint="0,0">
                                <GradientStop Offset="1.1" Color="Yellow" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="Transparent" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Grid.Background>
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="30" CenterX="20" />
                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="transform" X="0" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <Grid.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource animateme}"/>
                                </EventTrigger.Actions>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Grid.Triggers>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

**This is a UWP solution**

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Button x:Name="btn" Width="200" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid Background="LightGreen">
                    <TextBlock
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Text="TRY FOR FREE" />
                    <Grid
                        x:Name="grid"
                        Width="20"
                        Height="70">
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,2" EndPoint="0,0">
                                <GradientStop Offset="1.1" Color="Yellow" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="Transparent" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Grid.Background>
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="30" CenterX="20" />
                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="transform" X="0" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <Grid.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard x:Name="animation" Storyboard.TargetName="grid"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                                            <DoubleAnimation RepeatBehavior="Forever" From="-100" To="100" Duration="0:0:1" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger.Actions>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Grid.Triggers>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I started the animation in the code via Begin (). Thanks for the option you suggested, but unfortunately it shows me an exception and goes on to the following code
  UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };

Comment: Exception Message = "The text associated with this error code could not be found.\r\n\r\nFailed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.BeginStoryboard.Storyboard'. [Line: 56 Position: 58]"

Comment: Based on the exception, I see now that you have created a UWP project, not a WPF project, which my answer was in because that's what you included in your tags.  See my edited answer at the end.  Leave it up to MSFT to make WPF & UWP syntactically different :\

Comment: Thank you very much, everything works! I didn't think that UWP and WPF are so different)

Comment: You are missing `ClipToBounds="True"` somewhere (I've tried this because I was curious how good was reflection).